# Fast video stream start

Tags: ios, swift, video, video-streaming, avplayer

I am building an app that streams video content, something like TikTok. So you can swipe videos in table, and when new cell becomes visible the video starts playing. And it works great, except when you compare it to TikTok or Instagram or ect. My video starts streaming pretty fast but not always, it is very sensible to network quality, and sometimes even when network is great it still buffering too long. When comparing to TikTok, Instagram ... in same conditions they don't seam to have that problem. I am using JWPlayer as video hosting service, and AVPlayer as player. I am also doing async preload of assets before assigning them to PlayerItem. So my question is what else can I do to speed up video start. Do I need to do some special video preparations before uploading it to streaming service. (also I stream m3U8 files). Is there some set of presets that enables optimum streaming quality and start speed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

So theres a few things you can do.

1. HLS is apples preferred method of streaming to an apple device. So try to get that as much as possible for iOS devices.
2. The best practices when it comes to mobile streaming is offering multiple resolutions. The trick is to start with the lowest resolution available to get the video started. Then switch to a higher resolution once the speed is determined to be capable of higher resolutions. Generally this can be done quickly that the user doesn't really notice. YouTube is the best example of this tactic. HLS automatically does this, not sure about m3U8.
3. Assuming you are offering a UICollectionView or UITableView, try to start low resolution streams of every video on the screen in the background every time the scrolling stops. Not only does this allow you to do some cool preview stuff based off the buffer but when they click on it the video is already established. If thats too slow try just the middle video.
4. Edit the video in the background before upload to only be at the max resolution you expected it to be played at. There is no 4k resolution screen resolutions on any iOS device and probably never will be so cut down the amount of data.

Without getting more specifics this is all I got for now. Hope I understood your question correctly. Good luck!

Comment: basically I am doing all of the above, .m3u8 file is text file composed of lots of .mp4 links that point to various chunks of your video, in different resolutions as I understand and the whole point is that the player plays stream which is most probable to continue. So if I truest that AVPlayer is doing good job in determining which stream to play, and if I trust that JWPlayer has done good job with creating .m3u8 file, what else could I do to enhance my streaming performances.

Comment: Aside from the actual stream data itself, I would just make sure all other data processing and network calls are being done via async background tasks. Possibly create a dedicated qos specifically for that purpose. Should make it easier to tell what data needs to come to the main thread for display on the UI. Especially if you are going to do something like a miniplayer or something while the user scrolls, its a good way to keep the UI from slowing down.